# Replacing characters in a text using isalpha()

Tags: python, string, text, replace, isalpha

I want to remove the apostrophes from a text file given a certain condition, they aren't surrounded by letters. I've been able to figure out how to get the sum of apostrophes surrounded by letters with the following, using `isalpha()` method:

```
sum(textfile[i-1].isalpha() and textfile[i]=="'" and textfile[i+1].isalpha()
        for i in range(1,len(textfiel)-1))
```

But I would like to remove the apostrophes that are't surrounded in letters somehow, without importing extra modules.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to use the .isalpha() method for this?

I've had a try using the `isalpha()` combined with `text.replace()` but it seems hard to achieve.

Comment: Is this an exercise? It seems like a good use case for a simple regex, but that would involve import `re`.

Comment: `not text.isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should work:

```
s = "ab' c'd'e f'g' h' 'i"

indexes = [i for i in range(1, len(s)-1) if (s[i]=="'" and s[i-1].isalpha() and s[i+1].isalpha())]
''.join([element for i, element in enumerate(s) if i not in indexes])
```

Output

```
"ab' cde fg' h' 'i"
```